# API Not Found when called from Windows app but works on Postman

Tags: c#, api-design

I have developed a Web API. I have tested all methods with Postman and all methods  are working ok. So I developed a small windows app to code the calls before putting in a mobile application.

All Get methods are working ok but I am having a problem when I called a PUT method. I am passing the parameters with HttpContent but the response I got from my app is 404, Not Found. As I said if I use Postman it works ok.
here is the calling method:

```
private  string UpdateStudent()
{
   string retval = string.Empty;
   const string chave = "minhachave";
   string name = "MeuNome";
   string mob = "0987654321";
   string mail = "email@email.com";
   string psw = "MinhaSenha";
   var webapiuri = new Uri("https://localhost:44310");
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            
   List<string> param = new List<string>();
   param.Add(name);
   param.Add(mob);
   param.Add(mail);
   param.Add(psw);
   param.Add(chave);

   try
   {
     string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);
     var requestUrl = new Uri(webapiuri + "/api/Students/UpdateStd");
     using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString))
     {
       httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
       HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync(requestUrl, httpContent).Result;
       retval = response.ToString();
     }
   }
   catch(Exception err)
   {
     string error = err.Message;
     retval = error;
   }
   return retval;
}
```

And this is my API method:

```
 //Method to update registered student. Only update mobile, email and password
 //PUT: api/Students/UpdateStd
  [HttpPut]
  public string UpdateStd(string name, string mobile, string email, string password, string chave)
   {
     string valchave = "minhachave";
     string retval = string.Empty;
     bool chvval = valchave.Equals(chave);
     try
     {
       if (chvval == true)
       {
          tblRegister retstud = dtclmob.tblRegisters.Single(s => s.Name == name);
          if (retstud != null)
          {
            retstud.Email = email;
            retstud.Mobile = mobile;
            retstud.Password = password;
            dtclmob.SubmitChanges();
            retval = "Studentd info updated.";
          }
          else
          {
            retval = "Student not found.";
          }
        }
        else
        {
          retval = "WRONG KEY";
        }
      }
      catch(Exception err)
      {
        retval = err.Message;
      }
      return retval;
    }
```

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: The code _inside_ `UpdateStd` isn't relevant if your client code can't execute the method through an HTTP request.

Comment: Unrelated: Do not persist clear text passwords. Not even for "just learning" purposes. If the password doesn't matter just don't use any. If it does, make the effort to learn how to do it right.

Comment: What is the difference between the postman call and this one?

Comment: Thanks Fildor for your comment. The password is one of the parameters that can be updated, so it's relevant In the proper method it will be encrypted and can't not be recovered in case the student forget it. Thanks

Comment: Hi gunr2171.  Thanks for your comment. I just put the API code to give a full view of the issue, I thought it could help.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and reading I found my way.
First I change the API method I use the [FromBody] and use the Student model as parameters.
In my call method I used the same model where I added the new values to be updated.
That way I didn't have to worry about all the parametes to be passed.
Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to your API, you have to send the map/dictionary object as parameters to call your API, but you are only send the List, that is the reason your are getting API not found error.
I refector your UpdateStudent function and make it little better, please try it .

```
private string UpdateStudent()
{
    string retval = string.Empty;
    const string chave = "minhachave";
    string name = "MeuNome";
    string mob = "0987654321";
    string mail = "email@email.com";
    string psw = "MinhaSenha";
    var webapiuri = new Uri("https://localhost:44310");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    try
    {
        // Create an object to hold your parameters
        var parameters = new
        {
            name = name,
            mobile = mob,
            email = mail,
            password = psw,
            chave = chave
        };

        // Serialize the object to JSON
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

        // Create the request URL
        var requestUrl = new Uri(webapiuri + "/api/Students/UpdateStd");

        // Create the HttpContent for the request
        using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            // Send the PUT request
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync(requestUrl, httpContent).Result;

            // Check if the request was successful (status code 200 OK)
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                retval = "Student updated successfully!";
            }
            else
            {
                retval = $"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string error = err.Message;
        retval = error;
    }
    return retval;
}
```